# Upgrade Magento from 2.0.9 to 2.0.10

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am new in Magento.
I want to upgrade my Magento version **from 2.0.9 to 2.0.10**. I have goggling a lot.

I followed http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html but I get error **Couldn't resolve host 'repo.magento.com'**.

I have a site on [magemojo](https://magemojo.com/) so I want to upgrade in my localhost first and then in live server.

Please advise me.

Comment: Do you have install Magento through composer ? You can follow this : http://inchoo.net/magento-2/update-magento-2-installation/ or this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html

Comment: Thank you Franck Garnier for reply. That link is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the commands need to follow step by step. Go to Magento Root Folder & Execute

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.X.X --no-update // Replace 2.X.X with Your Needed Version Example: 2.1.2 which is latest
composer update //If your receive out of memory error then in apache php.ini please update your memory_limit XXXXM Example
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento --version
```

Comment: It worked !!!! Thanks a lot Ankit Shah :)